# How can I search apps by ProjectID or ClientID within Google?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I wonder if you could advise me? I have the ClientID of an application on Google, and I believe the first 12 characters refers to the projectID. My goal is to identify the name of the application.

Is there an API method that can be utilised to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Client id has no relation that I can see between the project id.   It can be anything.

To answer your question you cant use client id and project Id to try and figure out what project a client id was generated for.    I even checked [ID Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect?hl=en) to see if maybe that had information about the project it doesn't appear to either.

There is only one API that I am aware that allows you access to the projects on Google Developer console.  It is called the [Google Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/)  and it is extremely limited it doesn't list client id's associated with a project just the project.   [Google Developer console API](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-api/) is a post I did about that API not long after it was released.